# Cannot use "&" as a text attribute for a Button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This line gives an error. How can i use "&" for the text attribute?

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="&"                     <----- error here
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/or"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this:

```
&amp;
```

instead of:

```
&
```